# Multipage full width table in two-columns document without page break

Tags: tables, two-column, paper

I'm writing a paper using IEEEtrans, and need to include a long wide table (multipage, full width), but I can't get that the table starts at the beginning of a page without leaving so much empty space in the previous 2-column page.

I also need to repeat headers in each page, use captions, labels, and set column style as parragraph, but I think that it is more important to get first the desired location.

I have tried, `longtable`, `supertabular`, `xtabular` but can't get it work. I would like something like this mock-up:

[image]

Here is my MWE. Not sure how to generate dummy rows so it is quite long. Also, this example is using `article` class, I think it could work as well.

```
%tabletest
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{section}

\Blindtext[3]

\section{section}
\Blindtext[2]

\begin {table}[htb]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip 6pt\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{9}{r}}
\hline
M       & TA    & MO    & P & N & ID & CC & XC & KL \\
\hline
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Set of observations }
\end{table}

\Blindtext[2]
\section{section}
\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look at the `longtable` package! It might simplify this task a lot!

Comment: I tried, but from what I got and what I read It does not support a two-column context (?). Actually I am using the same table with  `longtable` in a book class document and wanted to use it in the paper, but didn't work as is.

Comment: Worst case you can cut the tabular manually and use two table* environments.

Comment: Since IEEE does not support \onecolumn, your best bet is to create a longtable in another document with the page size equal to the IEEE \textwidth and \textheight, then use \includegraphics[page=1] to copy it into table* environments one page at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This manually breaks the tabular, just to show it can be done.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{section}

\Blindtext[3]

\section{section}
\Blindtext[2]

\begin {table*}[tp]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip 6pt\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{9}{r}}
\hline
M       & TA    & MO    & P & N & ID & CC & XC & KL \\
\hline
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    & 
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\begin {table*}[tp]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip 6pt\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{9}{r}}
\hline
M       & TA    & MO    & P & N & ID & CC & XC & KL \\
\hline
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &  
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\begin {table*}[tp]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip 6pt\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{9}{r}}
\hline
M       & TA    & MO    & P & N & ID & CC & XC & KL \\
\hline
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Set of observations }
\end{table*}

\Blindtext[2]
\section{section}
\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

---

This creates a new document using longtable with the page size equal to IEEEtran text area.  You may also need to play with `\setcounter{table}` (here) and `\refstepcounter{table}` (main document) to get the table captions right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,noheadfoot,paperwidth=516pt,paperheight=696pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{\hskip 6pt\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{9}{r}}
\caption{Set of observations }
\hline
M       & TA    & MO    & P & N & ID & CC & XC & KL \\
\hline
\endhead
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
method  & 0.79  & 0.59  & - & - & 4  & 3  & 5  &    \\
ED  []  & 5     & 7     & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
CR      & 4     & 7     & - & - & 22 &    &    &    \\
NB[]    & 2     & 75    & - & - & 6  &    &    &    \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. Thanks! I will keep trying some options, but if I don't have success, I will implement this (Deadline is coming)