# How to put long table in two columns?

Tags: tables, longtable

is possible to put this longtable in two adiacent columns?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt  % '2pt' is not exactly much
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}
        l
        *{2}{S[table-format=3.1]}
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=1.1]
        @{} }
    \caption{Descriptive statistic for the twenty sites examined. Average and standard deviation are calculated for both devices's measurements.}
    \label{tab:descr_stat_es}\\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} &{L mean} &{L std} &{R mean} &{R std}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{}\\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} &{L mean} &{L std} &{R mean} &{R std}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]   \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    242WA   &   3375.7  &   33.2    &   ACC \\
    1003WA  &   2745.9  &   27.0    &   ACC \\
    175WA   &   2745.0  &   27.0    &   ACC \\
    150WA   &   2643.1  &   26.0    &   ACC \\
    195WA   &   2310.9  &   22.7    &   ACC \\
    176WA   &   2191.6  &   21.5    &   ACC \\
    158WA   &   1858.4  &   18.2    &   ACC \\
    136WA   &   2715.3  &   26.7    &   ACCa    \\
    145WA   &   2705.9  &   26.6    &   ACCa    \\
    134WA   &   2673.4  &   26.2    &   ACCa    \\
    56WA    &   2672.4  &   26.2    &   ACCa    \\
    96WA    &   2651.7  &   26.0    &   ACCa    \\
    135WA   &   2650.9  &   26.0    &   ACCa    \\
    143WA   &   2602.0  &   25.6    &   ACCa    \\
    57WA    &   2687.2  &   26.4    &   ACCb    \\
    66WA    &   2535.0  &   24.9    &   ACCb    \\
    90WA    &   2691.7  &   26.4    &   ANL \\
    98WA    &   2674.7  &   26.3    &   ANL \\
    121WA   &   2652.2  &   26.0    &   ANL \\
    153WA   &   2743.9  &   26.9    &   ARB \\
    154WA   &   2703.9  &   26.6    &   ARB \\
    155WA   &   2648.1  &   26.0    &   ARB \\
    197WA   &   2559.2  &   25.1    &   ARB \\
    162WB   &   2528.0  &   24.8    &   ARB \\
    149WA   &   2514.7  &   24.7    &   ARB \\
    1005WA  &   2067.5  &   20.3    &   ARB \\
    162WA   &   2011.6  &   19.8    &   ARB \\
    147WA   &   2783.5  &   27.3    &   bv  \\
    152WA   &   2500.4  &   24.6    &   bv  \\
    88WA    &   2540.4  &   24.9    &   CCA \\
    75WA    &   2509.7  &   24.6    &   CCA \\
    85WA    &   2487.5  &   24.4    &   CCA \\
    86WA    &   2152.8  &   21.1    &   CCA \\
    170WA   &   2256.0  &   22.2    &   CCVb    \\
    171WA   &   2371.2  &   23.3    &   CCVc    \\
    148WA   &   2341.7  &   23.0    &   CCVd    \\
    174WA   &   2024.8  &   19.9    &   CCVd    \\
    172WA   &   2719.5  &   26.7    &   CGV \\
    157WA   &   2664.1  &   26.2    &   CGV \\
    133WA   &   2652.0  &   26.0    &   CGV \\
    93WA    &   2598.4  &   25.5    &   CGV \\
    104WA   &   2596.6  &   25.5    &   CGV \\
    115WA   &   2578.4  &   25.3    &   CGV \\
    39WA    &   2685.2  &   26.4    &   CLF \\
    131WA   &   2637.5  &   25.9    &   CLF \\
    123WA   &   2616.9  &   25.7    &   CLF \\
    52WB    &   2745.7  &   27.0    &   FAF \\
    43WA    &   2737.8  &   26.9    &   FAF \\
    52WA    &   2735.5  &   26.9    &   FAF \\
    117WA   &   2724.9  &   26.8    &   FAF \\
    11WA    &   2675.8  &   26.3    &   FAF \\
    44WA    &   2664.0  &   26.2    &   FAF \\
    5WA &   2658.0  &   26.1    &   FAF \\
    2WA &   2645.9  &   26.0    &   FAF \\
    13WA    &   2637.8  &   25.9    &   FAF \\
    45WA    &   2632.1  &   25.8    &   FAF \\
    41WA    &   2614.3  &   25.7    &   FAF \\
    3WA &   2602.7  &   25.6    &   FAF \\
    168WA   &   2594.9  &   25.5    &   FAF \\
    46WA    &   2570.1  &   25.2    &   FAF \\
    6WA &   2566.2  &   25.2    &   FAF \\
    10WA    &   2546.0  &   25.0    &   FAF \\
    4WA &   2508.6  &   24.6    &   FAF \\
    47WA    &   2478.8  &   24.3    &   FAF \\
    209WB   &   2677.2  &   26.3    &   GOT \\
    209WA   &   2598.0  &   25.5    &   GOT \\
    246WA   &   2596.7  &   25.5    &   GOT \\
    249WA   &   2588.6  &   25.4    &   GOT \\
    69WA    &   2509.6  &   24.6    &   GOT \\
    208WA   &   2498.7  &   24.5    &   GOT \\
    68WA    &   2011.9  &   19.8    &   GOT \\
    1WA &   2831.3  &   27.8    &   GRE \\
    83WA    &   2803.9  &   27.5    &   GRE \\
    84WA    &   2800.5  &   27.5    &   GRE \\
    26WA    &   2786.8  &   27.4    &   GRE \\
    20WA    &   2773.0  &   27.2    &   GRE \\
    80WA    &   2761.9  &   27.1    &   GRE \\
    16WA    &   2759.7  &   27.1    &   GRE \\
    38WA    &   2757.0  &   27.1    &   GRE \\
    27WA    &   2743.1  &   26.9    &   GRE \\
    17WA    &   2741.3  &   26.9    &   GRE \\
    74WA    &   2721.9  &   26.7    &   GRE \\
    15WA    &   2681.8  &   26.3    &   GRE \\
    24WA    &   2656.3  &   26.1    &   GRE \\
    1002WB  &   3003.1  &   29.5    &   LVG \\
    72WA    &   2682.9  &   26.3    &   MAA \\
    70WA    &   2666.1  &   26.2    &   MAA \\
    73WA    &   2654.6  &   26.1    &   MAA \\
    71WA    &   2653.7  &   26.1    &   MAA \\
    91WA    &   2633.0  &   25.9    &   MAA \\
    248WA   &   2709.6  &   26.6    &   MAC \\
    284WA   &   2709.6  &   26.6    &   MAC \\
    161WA   &   2662.1  &   26.1    &   MAC \\
    132WA   &   2654.2  &   26.1    &   MAC \\
    240WA   &   2652.7  &   26.1    &   MAC \\
    94WA    &   2651.0  &   26.0    &   MAC \\
    103WA   &   2646.1  &   26.0    &   MAC \\
    199WA   &   2645.4  &   26.0    &   MAC \\
    111WA   &   2618.9  &   25.7    &   MAC \\
    102WA   &   2618.4  &   25.7    &   MAC \\
    59WA    &   2595.5  &   25.5    &   MAC \\
    28WA    &   2592.5  &   25.5    &   MAC \\
    58WA    &   2576.7  &   25.3    &   MAC \\
    286WA   &   2568.1  &   25.2    &   MAC \\
    284WB   &   2558.7  &   25.1    &   MAC \\
    99WA    &   2548.5  &   25.0    &   MAC \\
    65WA    &   2542.0  &   25.0    &   MAC \\
    140WA   &   2530.1  &   24.8    &   MAC \\
    116WA   &   2528.2  &   24.8    &   MAC \\
    7WA &   2527.2  &   24.8    &   MAC \\
    125WA   &   2523.4  &   24.8    &   MAC \\
    9WA &   2503.7  &   24.6    &   MAC \\
    126WA   &   2502.6  &   24.6    &   MAC \\
    55WA    &   2454.9  &   24.1    &   MAC \\
    95WA    &   2449.8  &   24.1    &   MAC \\
    89WA    &   2406.9  &   23.6    &   MAC \\
    54WA    &   2406.4  &   23.6    &   MAC \\
    64WA    &   2399.9  &   23.6    &   MAC \\
    245WA   &   2341.4  &   23.0    &   MAC \\
    8WA &   2315.6  &   22.7    &   MAC \\
    156WB   &   2314.1  &   22.7    &   MAC \\
    252WA   &   2228.8  &   21.9    &   MAC \\
    67WA    &   1994.3  &   19.6    &   MAC \\
    156WA   &   1372.6  &   13.5    &   MAC \\
    151WA   &   2556.3  &   25.1    &   MACa    \\
    127WA   &   2689.5  &   26.4    &   MAS \\
    141WA   &   2669.9  &   26.2    &   MAS \\
    79WA    &   2966.7  &   29.1    &   MDD \\
    77WA    &   2793.7  &   27.4    &   MDD \\
    76WA    &   2763.3  &   27.1    &   MDD \\
    130WA   &   2717.2  &   26.7    &   MDD \\
    40WA    &   2752.6  &   27.0    &   MRQ \\
    49WA    &   2701.6  &   26.5    &   MRQ \\
    42WA    &   2620.1  &   25.7    &   MRQ \\
    205WA   &   2670.9  &   26.2    &   MRR \\
    163WA   &   2453.8  &   24.1    &   MVE \\
    203WA   &   2110.4  &   20.7    &   MVE \\
    253WA   &   3770.2  &   37.0    &   OMT \\
    167WA   &   2691.6  &   26.4    &   OMT \\
    137WA   &   2685.5  &   26.4    &   OMT \\
    101WA   &   2677.4  &   26.3    &   OMT \\
    139WB   &   2676.8  &   26.3    &   OMT \\
    138WA   &   2675.4  &   26.3    &   OMT \\
    92WA    &   2675.1  &   26.3    &   OMT \\
    165WA   &   2669.6  &   26.2    &   OMT \\
    254WA   &   2668.6  &   26.2    &   OMT \\
    183WA   &   2655.3  &   26.1    &   OMT \\
    108WA   &   2647.0  &   26.0    &   OMT \\
    105WA   &   2640.9  &   25.9    &   OMT \\
    285WB   &   2639.7  &   25.9    &   OMT \\
    110WA   &   2634.4  &   25.9    &   OMT \\
    107WB   &   2630.7  &   25.8    &   OMT \\
    139WA   &   2627.9  &   25.8    &   OMT \\
    164WA   &   2625.1  &   25.8    &   OMT \\
    61WA    &   2624.6  &   25.8    &   OMT \\
    107WA   &   2619.1  &   25.7    &   OMT \\
    232WA   &   2619.0  &   25.7    &   OMT \\
    233WA   &   2613.2  &   25.7    &   OMT \\
    63WA    &   2612.3  &   25.6    &   OMT \\
    109WA   &   2604.8  &   25.6    &   OMT \\
    100WA   &   2601.8  &   25.6    &   OMT \\
    142WA   &   2600.8  &   25.5    &   OMT \\
    62WA    &   2596.4  &   25.5    &   OMT \\
    129WA   &   2591.5  &   25.4    &   OMT \\
    165WC   &   2583.2  &   25.4    &   OMT \\
    106WA   &   2581.4  &   25.3    &   OMT \\
    114WA   &   2580.2  &   25.3    &   OMT \\
    165WB   &   2557.5  &   25.1    &   OMT \\
    110WB   &   2547.8  &   25.0    &   OMT \\
    113WA   &   2496.4  &   24.5    &   OMT \\
    60WA    &   2313.0  &   22.7    &   OMT \\
    204WA   &   2615.9  &   25.7    &   OST \\
    204WB   &   2578.3  &   25.3    &   OST \\
    207WB   &   2756.1  &   27.1    &   PRC \\
    207WA   &   2600.1  &   25.5    &   PRC \\
    50WA    &   2765.0  &   27.2    &   PRS \\
    118WA   &   2732.4  &   26.8    &   PRS \\
    78WA    &   2686.4  &   26.4    &   PRS \\
    53WA    &   2680.1  &   26.3    &   PRS \\
    48WA    &   2676.4  &   26.3    &   PRS \\
    81WA    &   2647.7  &   26.0    &   PRS \\
    82WA    &   2612.0  &   25.6    &   PRS \\
    18WA    &   2673.5  &   26.2    &   PSM \\
    19WA    &   2672.3  &   26.2    &   PSM \\
    21WA    &   2661.5  &   26.1    &   PSM \\
    34WA    &   2657.1  &   26.1    &   PSM \\
    14WA    &   2653.6  &   26.1    &   PSM \\
    29WA    &   2649.0  &   26.0    &   PSM \\
    30WA    &   2627.7  &   25.8    &   PSM \\
    31WA    &   2610.5  &   25.6    &   PSM \\
    36WA    &   2575.4  &   25.3    &   PSM \\
    23WA    &   2542.5  &   25.0    &   PSM \\
    32WA    &   2522.3  &   24.8    &   PSM \\
    22WA    &   2501.1  &   24.6    &   PSM \\
    25WA    &   2497.6  &   24.5    &   PSM \\
    37WA    &   2418.5  &   23.8    &   PSM \\
    35WA    &   2393.1  &   23.5    &   PSM \\
    33WA    &   2200.6  &   21.6    &   PSM \\
    202WA   &   3375.7  &   33.2    &   pv  \\
    128WA   &   2684.1  &   26.4    &   RET \\
    97WA    &   2677.8  &   26.3    &   RET \\
    87WA    &   2554.9  &   25.1    &   RET \\
    124WA   &   2826.9  &   27.8    &   SSR \\
    122WA   &   2786.8  &   27.4    &   SSR \\
    244WB   &   2718.0  &   26.7    &   STO \\
    244WA   &   2702.1  &   26.5    &   STO \\
    120WA   &   2675.9  &   26.3    &   STO \\
    112WA   &   2660.3  &   26.1    &   STO \\
    12WA    &   2654.6  &   26.1    &   VEU \\
    51WA    &   2577.1  &   25.3    &   VEU \\
    119WA   &   2773.8  &   27.2    &   VINa    \\
\end{longtable}
\onehalfspacing 

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460290/multipage-full-width-table-in-two-columns-document-without-page-break

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank for your reply. I have a one-column document (report class)

Comment: Probably related/helpful: [Dealing with very long table - split into columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134381/134144)

Comment: Please also recheck your column definitions. Currently you define 5 columns and headers, but the table only contains data on 4 columns. Also, do not use `S` type columns for columns that do not contain numbers (such as column 4) and also make sure that the `table-format` of your `S` type columns matches the numbers that are present in the corresponding columns. Probably you want to use something like `\begin{longtable}{@{}
        r
        S[table-format=4.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        cc
        @{} }` instead.

Comment: Please also keep in mind tht your table is currently wider than half of the textwidth. With your current setup, two of them will most likely not fit  into the textwidth side-by-side.

Answer (score 3):

Just make yourself the two-column tabular:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt  % '2pt' is not exactly much
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}% {@{} r S[table-format=4.1] S[table-format=2.1] cc c r
    % S[table-format=4.1] S[table-format=2.1] cc@{} }
  {lrrcc|lrrc}
% \begin{longtable}{@{}
%         l
%         *{2}{S[table-format=3.1]}
%         S[table-format=2.1]
%         S[table-format=1.1]
%         @{} }
\caption{Descriptive statistic for the twenty sites examined. Average and standard deviation are calculated for both devices's measurements.}
    \label{tab:descr_stat_es}                                                          \\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} & {L mean} & {L std} & {R mean} &  & {Geological fm.} & {L mean} & {L std} & {R mean}      \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
 %   \caption[]{}                                                                       \\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} & {L mean} & {L std} & {R mean} &  & {Geological fm.} & {L mean} & {L std} & {R mean}          \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]   \multicolumn{9}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
242WA                & 3375.7   & 33.2    & ACC      &  & 99WA  & 2548.5 & 25.0 & MAC  \\ 
1003WA               & 2745.9   & 27.0    & ACC      &  & 65WA  & 2542.0 & 25.0 & MAC  \\ 
175WA                & 2745.0   & 27.0    & ACC      &  & 140WA & 2530.1 & 24.8 & MAC  \\ 
150WA                & 2643.1   & 26.0    & ACC      &  & 116WA & 2528.2 & 24.8 & MAC  \\ 
195WA                & 2310.9   & 22.7    & ACC      &  & 7WA   & 2527.2 & 24.8 & MAC  \\ 
176WA                & 2191.6   & 21.5    & ACC      &  & 125WA & 2523.4 & 24.8 & MAC  \\ 
158WA                & 1858.4   & 18.2    & ACC      &  & 9WA   & 2503.7 & 24.6 & MAC  \\ 
136WA                & 2715.3   & 26.7    & ACCa     &  & 126WA & 2502.6 & 24.6 & MAC  \\ 
145WA                & 2705.9   & 26.6    & ACCa     &  & 55WA  & 2454.9 & 24.1 & MAC  \\ 
134WA                & 2673.4   & 26.2    & ACCa     &  & 95WA  & 2449.8 & 24.1 & MAC  \\ 
56WA                 & 2672.4   & 26.2    & ACCa     &  & 89WA  & 2406.9 & 23.6 & MAC  \\ 
96WA                 & 2651.7   & 26.0    & ACCa     &  & 54WA  & 2406.4 & 23.6 & MAC  \\ 
135WA                & 2650.9   & 26.0    & ACCa     &  & 64WA  & 2399.9 & 23.6 & MAC  \\ 
143WA                & 2602.0   & 25.6    & ACCa     &  & 245WA & 2341.4 & 23.0 & MAC  \\ 
57WA                 & 2687.2   & 26.4    & ACCb     &  & 8WA   & 2315.6 & 22.7 & MAC  \\ 
66WA                 & 2535.0   & 24.9    & ACCb     &  & 156WB & 2314.1 & 22.7 & MAC  \\ 
90WA                 & 2691.7   & 26.4    & ANL      &  & 252WA & 2228.8 & 21.9 & MAC  \\ 
98WA                 & 2674.7   & 26.3    & ANL      &  & 67WA  & 1994.3 & 19.6 & MAC  \\ 
121WA                & 2652.2   & 26.0    & ANL      &  & 156WA & 1372.6 & 13.5 & MAC  \\ 
153WA                & 2743.9   & 26.9    & ARB      &  & 151WA & 2556.3 & 25.1 & MACa \\ 
154WA                & 2703.9   & 26.6    & ARB      &  & 127WA & 2689.5 & 26.4 & MAS  \\ 
155WA                & 2648.1   & 26.0    & ARB      &  & 141WA & 2669.9 & 26.2 & MAS  \\ 
197WA                & 2559.2   & 25.1    & ARB      &  & 79WA  & 2966.7 & 29.1 & MDD  \\ 
162WB                & 2528.0   & 24.8    & ARB      &  & 77WA  & 2793.7 & 27.4 & MDD  \\ 
149WA                & 2514.7   & 24.7    & ARB      &  & 76WA  & 2763.3 & 27.1 & MDD  \\ 
1005WA               & 2067.5   & 20.3    & ARB      &  & 130WA & 2717.2 & 26.7 & MDD  \\ 
162WA                & 2011.6   & 19.8    & ARB      &  & 40WA  & 2752.6 & 27.0 & MRQ  \\ 
147WA                & 2783.5   & 27.3    & bv       &  & 49WA  & 2701.6 & 26.5 & MRQ  \\ 
152WA                & 2500.4   & 24.6    & bv       &  & 42WA  & 2620.1 & 25.7 & MRQ  \\ 
88WA                 & 2540.4   & 24.9    & CCA      &  & 205WA & 2670.9 & 26.2 & MRR  \\ 
75WA                 & 2509.7   & 24.6    & CCA      &  & 163WA & 2453.8 & 24.1 & MVE  \\ 
85WA                 & 2487.5   & 24.4    & CCA      &  & 203WA & 2110.4 & 20.7 & MVE  \\ 
86WA                 & 2152.8   & 21.1    & CCA      &  & 253WA & 3770.2 & 37.0 & OMT  \\ 
170WA                & 2256.0   & 22.2    & CCVb     &  & 167WA & 2691.6 & 26.4 & OMT  \\ 
171WA                & 2371.2   & 23.3    & CCVc     &  & 137WA & 2685.5 & 26.4 & OMT  \\ 
148WA                & 2341.7   & 23.0    & CCVd     &  & 101WA & 2677.4 & 26.3 & OMT  \\ 
174WA                & 2024.8   & 19.9    & CCVd     &  & 139WB & 2676.8 & 26.3 & OMT  \\ 
172WA                & 2719.5   & 26.7    & CGV      &  & 138WA & 2675.4 & 26.3 & OMT  \\ 
157WA                & 2664.1   & 26.2    & CGV      &  & 92WA  & 2675.1 & 26.3 & OMT  \\ 
133WA                & 2652.0   & 26.0    & CGV      &  & 165WA & 2669.6 & 26.2 & OMT  \\ 
93WA                 & 2598.4   & 25.5    & CGV      &  & 254WA & 2668.6 & 26.2 & OMT  \\ 
104WA                & 2596.6   & 25.5    & CGV      &  & 183WA & 2655.3 & 26.1 & OMT  \\ 
115WA                & 2578.4   & 25.3    & CGV      &  & 108WA & 2647.0 & 26.0 & OMT  \\ 
39WA                 & 2685.2   & 26.4    & CLF      &  & 105WA & 2640.9 & 25.9 & OMT  \\ 
131WA                & 2637.5   & 25.9    & CLF      &  & 285WB & 2639.7 & 25.9 & OMT  \\ 
123WA                & 2616.9   & 25.7    & CLF      &  & 110WA & 2634.4 & 25.9 & OMT  \\ 
52WB                 & 2745.7   & 27.0    & FAF      &  & 107WB & 2630.7 & 25.8 & OMT  \\ 
43WA                 & 2737.8   & 26.9    & FAF      &  & 139WA & 2627.9 & 25.8 & OMT  \\ 
52WA                 & 2735.5   & 26.9    & FAF      &  & 164WA & 2625.1 & 25.8 & OMT  \\ 
117WA                & 2724.9   & 26.8    & FAF      &  & 61WA  & 2624.6 & 25.8 & OMT  \\ 
11WA                 & 2675.8   & 26.3    & FAF      &  & 107WA & 2619.1 & 25.7 & OMT  \\ 
44WA                 & 2664.0   & 26.2    & FAF      &  & 232WA & 2619.0 & 25.7 & OMT  \\ 
5WA                  & 2658.0   & 26.1    & FAF      &  & 233WA & 2613.2 & 25.7 & OMT  \\ 
2WA                  & 2645.9   & 26.0    & FAF      &  & 63WA  & 2612.3 & 25.6 & OMT  \\ 
13WA                 & 2637.8   & 25.9    & FAF      &  & 109WA & 2604.8 & 25.6 & OMT  \\ 
45WA                 & 2632.1   & 25.8    & FAF      &  & 100WA & 2601.8 & 25.6 & OMT  \\ 
41WA                 & 2614.3   & 25.7    & FAF      &  & 142WA & 2600.8 & 25.5 & OMT  \\ 
3WA                  & 2602.7   & 25.6    & FAF      &  & 62WA  & 2596.4 & 25.5 & OMT  \\ 
168WA                & 2594.9   & 25.5    & FAF      &  & 129WA & 2591.5 & 25.4 & OMT  \\ 
46WA                 & 2570.1   & 25.2    & FAF      &  & 165WC & 2583.2 & 25.4 & OMT  \\ 
6WA                  & 2566.2   & 25.2    & FAF      &  & 106WA & 2581.4 & 25.3 & OMT  \\ 
10WA                 & 2546.0   & 25.0    & FAF      &  & 114WA & 2580.2 & 25.3 & OMT  \\ 
4WA                  & 2508.6   & 24.6    & FAF      &  & 165WB & 2557.5 & 25.1 & OMT  \\ 
47WA                 & 2478.8   & 24.3    & FAF      &  & 110WB & 2547.8 & 25.0 & OMT  \\ 
209WB                & 2677.2   & 26.3    & GOT      &  & 113WA & 2496.4 & 24.5 & OMT  \\ 
209WA                & 2598.0   & 25.5    & GOT      &  & 60WA  & 2313.0 & 22.7 & OMT  \\ 
246WA                & 2596.7   & 25.5    & GOT      &  & 204WA & 2615.9 & 25.7 & OST  \\ 
249WA                & 2588.6   & 25.4    & GOT      &  & 204WB & 2578.3 & 25.3 & OST  \\ 
69WA                 & 2509.6   & 24.6    & GOT      &  & 207WB & 2756.1 & 27.1 & PRC  \\ 
208WA                & 2498.7   & 24.5    & GOT      &  & 207WA & 2600.1 & 25.5 & PRC  \\ 
68WA                 & 2011.9   & 19.8    & GOT      &  & 50WA  & 2765.0 & 27.2 & PRS  \\ 
1WA                  & 2831.3   & 27.8    & GRE      &  & 118WA & 2732.4 & 26.8 & PRS  \\ 
83WA                 & 2803.9   & 27.5    & GRE      &  & 78WA  & 2686.4 & 26.4 & PRS  \\ 
84WA                 & 2800.5   & 27.5    & GRE      &  & 53WA  & 2680.1 & 26.3 & PRS  \\ 
26WA                 & 2786.8   & 27.4    & GRE      &  & 48WA  & 2676.4 & 26.3 & PRS  \\ 
20WA                 & 2773.0   & 27.2    & GRE      &  & 81WA  & 2647.7 & 26.0 & PRS  \\ 
80WA                 & 2761.9   & 27.1    & GRE      &  & 82WA  & 2612.0 & 25.6 & PRS  \\ 
16WA                 & 2759.7   & 27.1    & GRE      &  & 18WA  & 2673.5 & 26.2 & PSM  \\ 
38WA                 & 2757.0   & 27.1    & GRE      &  & 19WA  & 2672.3 & 26.2 & PSM  \\ 
27WA                 & 2743.1   & 26.9    & GRE      &  & 21WA  & 2661.5 & 26.1 & PSM  \\ 
17WA                 & 2741.3   & 26.9    & GRE      &  & 34WA  & 2657.1 & 26.1 & PSM  \\ 
74WA                 & 2721.9   & 26.7    & GRE      &  & 14WA  & 2653.6 & 26.1 & PSM  \\ 
15WA                 & 2681.8   & 26.3    & GRE      &  & 29WA  & 2649.0 & 26.0 & PSM  \\ 
24WA                 & 2656.3   & 26.1    & GRE      &  & 30WA  & 2627.7 & 25.8 & PSM  \\ 
1002WB               & 3003.1   & 29.5    & LVG      &  & 31WA  & 2610.5 & 25.6 & PSM  \\ 
72WA                 & 2682.9   & 26.3    & MAA      &  & 36WA  & 2575.4 & 25.3 & PSM  \\ 
70WA                 & 2666.1   & 26.2    & MAA      &  & 23WA  & 2542.5 & 25.0 & PSM  \\ 
73WA                 & 2654.6   & 26.1    & MAA      &  & 32WA  & 2522.3 & 24.8 & PSM  \\ 
71WA                 & 2653.7   & 26.1    & MAA      &  & 22WA  & 2501.1 & 24.6 & PSM  \\ 
91WA                 & 2633.0   & 25.9    & MAA      &  & 25WA  & 2497.6 & 24.5 & PSM  \\ 
248WA                & 2709.6   & 26.6    & MAC      &  & 37WA  & 2418.5 & 23.8 & PSM  \\ 
284WA                & 2709.6   & 26.6    & MAC      &  & 35WA  & 2393.1 & 23.5 & PSM  \\ 
161WA                & 2662.1   & 26.1    & MAC      &  & 33WA  & 2200.6 & 21.6 & PSM  \\ 
132WA                & 2654.2   & 26.1    & MAC      &  & 202WA & 3375.7 & 33.2 & pv   \\ 
240WA                & 2652.7   & 26.1    & MAC      &  & 128WA & 2684.1 & 26.4 & RET  \\ 
94WA                 & 2651.0   & 26.0    & MAC      &  & 97WA  & 2677.8 & 26.3 & RET  \\ 
103WA                & 2646.1   & 26.0    & MAC      &  & 87WA  & 2554.9 & 25.1 & RET  \\ 
199WA                & 2645.4   & 26.0    & MAC      &  & 124WA & 2826.9 & 27.8 & SSR  \\ 
111WA                & 2618.9   & 25.7    & MAC      &  & 122WA & 2786.8 & 27.4 & SSR  \\ 
102WA                & 2618.4   & 25.7    & MAC      &  & 244WB & 2718.0 & 26.7 & STO  \\ 
59WA                 & 2595.5   & 25.5    & MAC      &  & 244WA & 2702.1 & 26.5 & STO  \\ 
28WA                 & 2592.5   & 25.5    & MAC      &  & 120WA & 2675.9 & 26.3 & STO  \\ 
58WA                 & 2576.7   & 25.3    & MAC      &  & 112WA & 2660.3 & 26.1 & STO  \\ 
286WA                & 2568.1   & 25.2    & MAC      &  & 12WA  & 2654.6 & 26.1 & VEU  \\ 
284WB                & 2558.7   & 25.1    & MAC      &  & 51WA  & 2577.1 & 25.3 & VEU  \\ 
                     &          &         &          &  & 119WA & 2773.8 & 27.2 & VINa \\ 

\end{longtable}
%\onehalfspacing 

\end{document}
```

First page looks like this:

[image: pic of tabular]

You probably have the data somewhere in a spreadsheet. Make a two-column table in the spreadsheet. I made deliberately an empty column. And then I exported the whole thing into a *.tex file.

I did not sort out your siunitx-trouble, though.